# How to prevent from a latch when I write a DFF

Tags: verilog

I'm writing a verilog code,

And when I passed my code to my members,

They said it has latch in my code.

Tell me in the code space I want to build  a DFF is a latch,

But I can't figure out that because I think I use posedge clk to trigger always,

And not use if/case in block, why there still has latch.

the following is my code, please help me to figure out this, thanks.

```
   always@(posedge clk_a) begin
      a1 <= in;
   end

   always@(posedge clk_b) begin
      b1 <= a1;
      out <= b1;
   end
```

Comment: The code you show should not generate a latch

Comment: Thanks for response, I edit my question, will it has latch?

Comment: or have D latch

Comment: because my friend tell me, must have rst trigger in this always block,

Comment: You need to have a reset if you want the flip-flop to be reset with an async reset signal. This is often a good idea, but not strictly necessary.

Comment: thanks for answer.  I edit my question.  I was originally writing a 2FF synchronizer and my membor tell me if I don't add reset in it, there will be a latch, right?

Comment: This will not create a latch  under any circumstance, what it will create are D-flip flops which never reset. 

This should not cause any issue, although if you're designing an ASIC it is considered best practice to have an async reset associated with every `always` block. If you are on an FPGA then the opposite is often true.

Comment: you have flops, no latches. A flop can potentially be modeled as  two back-to-back latches.